# Ошибка: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on bool in…

Tags: php, sqlite

Выдаёт ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on bool in… Не пойму, в чём может быть проблема. Вывод  var_dump($req); — bool(false).

```
 public function add(Post $post): void
    {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO posts SET title = :title, content = :content';

        $req = $this->db->prepare($sql);

    var_dump($req);

        $req->bindValue(':title', $post->getTitle(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $req->bindValue(':content', $post->getContent(), \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $req->execute();
    }
```

Comment: А для чего обратный слеш у параметра типа PDO::PARAM_STR?

Comment: INSERT INTO posts (title, content) VALUES (:title, :content)

Comment: Да давно где-то читал, что нужно для экранирования :)) Но, это не влияет никак), так, привычка

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':' in… имеет ввиду здесь $req->bindValue(':title', $post->getTitle(), PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: Угадывать ошибки здесь некому, научитесь пользоваться функцией `errorInfo` для PDO.

Comment: PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => HY000 [1] => 1 [2] => near "SET": syntax error )